# How can I decide whether to create a private gem server or just host on GitHub?

Tags: ruby, github, rubygems

I'm in a situation where I need to share gems that are in private GitHub repos with other team members. It seems like my options are to create a private gem server or just have these other engineers source the gems from GitHub directly by specifying in that in `Gemfile`s.

What are the tradeoffs to these two approaches and how would I know when to go all the way with a private gem server?

Comment: github private is free now, so it has that going for it.

Comment: if the cost of running a t2.micro on AWS 24/7 isn't considered an issue, would there be any other reasons to go with GitHub instead?

Comment: "github private is free now" I don't think that's correct, @maxpleaner. All paid accounts have unlimited private repositories, but free accounts don't include any private repositories. https://github.com/blog/2164-introducing-unlimited-private-repositories

Comment: If it's only a small number of gems, for a small number of people, then setting up permissions in Github is a quick solution. But if you want a more sustainable, long-term solution (i.e. if the Github permissions will need frequently changing due to changing team members and/or repositories) then a private gem server is a better choice.

Comment: For example, I work at a small company where all employees have (at least) "read only" access to all private repositories by default - so there is no real need for us to create a gem server. On the other hand, perhaps we will one day find that it becomes cumbersome maintaining deployment keys across many production systems, to give access to the required gems.

Comment: Essentially, I don't have a black-and-white answer to give you. It's in your own judgement what will likely be easiest to maintain, given the structure of your company/permissions/deployments.